# SendGrid templates how to parse array variable?

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig, sendgrid

I use SendGrid and I crate template and give in template variable 'name' like this:

why addSubstitution need array parameters and how this array parsing in template ?

```
$name = array('Test');
//
->addSubstitution(":name", $name)
```

befor I use tqig and send all template and in twig I have good algorithmization function  like this

```
{% for skill in project.projectSkills %}
{{ skill }}
{% endfor %}
```

how do this in template sendGrid ? Or how work with array in template sendGrid ?

templte in sendGrid:

```
Hello :name,
Hot work with array :skill ?
<%body%>

With Best Regards,

Your Library Tester
```

Code

```
    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($this->container->getParameter('sendgrid_key'));

    $email = new \SendGrid\Email();
    $name = array('testName');
    $skills = array('skill1', 'skill2', 'skill3') ;

    $email
    ->addTo('myEmail@test.com')
    ->setFrom(''test@test.com)
    ->setFromName('Test')
    ->setSubject('subject')
    ->setText('I\'m text!')
    ->setHtml('<strong>I\'m HTML!</strong>')
    ->addFilter('templates', 'enabled', 1)
    ->addFilter('templates', 'template_id', $template_id)
    ->addSubstitution(":skill", $skill)
    ->addSubstitution(":name", $name);


    $result = $sendgrid->send($email);
```

Answer (score 0):

The SendGrid template engine currently doesn't support enumerations or conditionals, so you need to perform that logic before passing the content. Using [section tags](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/section_tags.html) might make sense.

Comment: you mean in template can add some <%tag%>  hot to php set this <%tag%>, like this - ->addSection($skill, ':tag') or how ?